# php: Parse string from html

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have opened an HTML file using

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.html')
```

and want to parse the line including "ParseThis":

```
 <h1 class=\"header\">ParseThis<\/h1>
```

As you can see, it's within an `h1` tag (the first `h1` tag from the file). How can I get the text "ParseThis"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DOM](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this.

```
// Load remote file, supress parse errors
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/file.html');
libxml_clear_errors();

// use XPath to find all nodes with a class attribute of header
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//h1[@class="header"]');

// output first item's content
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Also see

- [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)
- [More examples by me with DOM.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+php+dom)

*Marking this CW because I have answered this before, but I am too lazy to find the duplicate*

Answer (score 4):

Use this function.

```
<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.html');

echo get_string_between($data, '<h1 class=\"header\">', '<\/h1>');
```

Comment: It may work for this case, but you should be using DOM selectors or XML navigation.

Comment: I prefer this because it work faster than DOM and when there are very simple requirements like this, I use my `get_string_between` :)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is the first h1 tag, getting it should be fairly trivial:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$h1 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');
echo $h1->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php