# php - Regex - space and non-capturing group

Tags: php, regex

I have this kind of string :

```
Blabla1 Blaabla2<br />  Blaabla3 Blaabla4
```

I'm trying to explode each word where there is a `" "` or `"<br />"` with `preg_split` .

What I exepect :

```
Blabla1
Blabla2 <br />
Blaabla3
Blaabla4
```

I tried with this regex `(?:(<br\s))|\s` but don't manage to exlude `"/>"`

http://regexr.com/3aqs0

Thanks !

Comment: Are you wanting to retain the `<br />`? Your expected output shows it retained ...

Comment: Does the text have other HTML tags within it?

Comment: @hwnd yes I want it :)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes like <strong> <em> ...

Comment: It would probably be clearer if you converted all the `<br/>` to spaces, and then did the split on spaces.  You don't need to do everything in one single regex.

Comment: @AndyLester but I need to keep <br /> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not more HTML, it's okay to use RegEx. [Otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements) [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083076/php-way-of-parsing-html-string) [are many better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591675/php-parse-string-from-html).

Use `<br(\s\/)?>\K|\s`:

```
$matches = preg_split('/<br(\s\/)?>\K|\s/',$string);
```

This will also work for `<br>` (which is correct HTML too)

Consider the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, because there are going to be empty elements using your example string:

```
preg_split('/<br(\s\/)?>\K|\s/',$string,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**Update:** To keep the `<br />`, you need to reset the match using `\K`. There is a good example on this in [the language reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> \K can be used to reset the match start since PHP 5.2.4. For example,
>   the pattern foo\Kbar matches "foobar", but reports that it has matched
>   "bar". The use of \K does not interfere with the setting of captured
>   substrings. For example, when the pattern (foo)\Kbar matches "foobar",
>   the first substring is still set to "foo".

Comment: Also he can use PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY for avoiding empty elements, like 
    preg_split('/(?:(<br\s\/>))|\s/',$string,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

Comment: Correct, forgot the flags :) I will add this

Comment: almost perfect :) ... How to keep the <br/> after blabla2 ?

Comment: @Marc Works Nice ! :) And now,  If in my string I have two or more consecutive <br /> ? like  `$str = 'Blabla1 Blaabla2<br /><br />  Blaabla3 Blaabla4';`  How to do ?

Comment: find solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671967/php-improve-regex-space-and-non-capturing-group/29672376#29672440 . Thanks for all !

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this:

```
$str = 'Blabla1 Blaabla2<br />  Blaabla3 Blaabla4';
$results = preg_split('~(?:<br[^>]*>\s*\K|\s+)~', $str);
print_r($results);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Blabla1
    [1] => Blaabla2<br />  
    [2] => Blaabla3
    [3] => Blaabla4
)
```

Comment: it works nice thx  !! but can you explain all please for my information :) . It interest me !

Comment: Are you just wanting to split on whitespace not inside HTML? And note this will split the `<br>` if there is a space preceding it as well. I am not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: In fact, I'm using a text EDITOR (CKEDITOR). When I save the textarea in DataBase, I need to keep all tags (<br>, <strong>, <em>, <u>). Then when I reload the page with my text Editor I need to split each word with his associated tags because my text editor is coupled with a audio player (Jwplayer) which underline each word in function of time avanced...

Comment: Other question, If in my string I have two or more consecutive <br /> ? like `$str = 'Blabla1 Blaabla2<br /><br /> Blaabla3 Blaabla4';` How to do ?

Comment: You could do `(?:(?:<br[^>]*>\s*)+\K|\s+)`