# PHP - Improve Regex (space and non-capturing group)

Tags: php, regex

I have this kind of string :

```
$string = "<strong>Blabla1</strong> Blaabla2<br /> Blaabla3 <strong>Blaabla4</strong> Blaabla5 Blaabla6<br /><br /> Blaabla7 <span style='color:#B22222;'>Blaabla8</span> Blaabla9";
```

I'm trying to explode each word where there is a `" "` or `"<br />"` with `preg_split` .

**My conditions :**

For each word (`Blablax`), I need to keep his tags like `<strong>`, `<span>`, `<em>`... but split him after a `<br />` or more `<br />`

I tried this, thanks to another post on stackoverflow :

```
preg_split('/<br(\s\/)?>\K|\s/',$string,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array (size=12)
  0 => string '<strong>Blabla1</strong>' (length=24)
  1 => string 'Blaabla2<br />' (length=14)
  2 => string 'Blaabla3' (length=8)
  3 => string '<strong>Blaabla4</strong>' (length=25)
  4 => string 'Blaabla5' (length=8)
  5 => string 'Blaabla6<br />' (length=14)
  6 => string '<br' (length=3)
  7 => string '/>' (length=2)
  8 => string 'Blaabla7' (length=8)
  9 => string '<span' (length=5)
  10 => string 'style='color:#B22222;'>Blaabla8</span>' (length=38)
  11 => string 'Blaabla9' (length=8)
```

Everything works **except** for `index 6` and `index 7` (see above in OUTPUT) and `index 9` and `index 10`

**What I'll exepect :**

```
array (size=12)
      0 => string '<strong>Blabla1</strong>' (length=24)
      1 => string 'Blaabla2<br />' (length=14)
      2 => string 'Blaabla3' (length=8)
      3 => string '<strong>Blaabla4</strong>' (length=25)
      4 => string 'Blaabla5' (length=8)
      5 => string 'Blaabla6<br /><br />' (length=14)
      6 => string 'Blaabla7' (length=8)
      7 => string '<span style='color:#B22222;'>Blaabla8</span>' (length=45)
      8 => string 'Blaabla9' (length=8)
```

See `index 5` and  `index 7`

My regex works if I have just one `<br />` but if more than one, there is a mistakes... idem if I have a `<span style...>`

Thanks !

Comment: try `preg_split('/<br(\s\/)?>\K|\s/g',$string,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
`

Comment: Why is there an extra `<br />` at index 1? It does not present in the input.

Comment: @nhahtdh my bad... I edited my post... there is no extra `<br />` at the index 1...

Comment: Looking at your requirement for index 7, I think you are better off using a PHP parser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "<strong>Blabla1</strong> Blaabla2<br /> Blaabla3 <strong>Blaabla4</strong> Blaabla5 Blaabla6<br /><br /> Blaabla7 <span style='color:#B22222;'>Blaabla8</span> Blaabla9";

$matches = preg_split('/(<br.*?>|<span.*>)+\K|\s/sim', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );

var_dump($matches);
    /*
      array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "<strong>Blabla1</strong>"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Blaabla2<br />"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla3"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "<strong>Blaabla4</strong>"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla5"
  [5]=>
  string(20) "Blaabla6<br /><br />"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla7"
  [7]=>
  string(44) "<span style='color:#B22222;'>Blaabla8</span>"
  [8]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla9"
}
    */
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/q8xrvd)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your expected array at index 5 and index 7, you probably want this regex:

```
preg_split('~(?:</?[a-zA-Z0-9][^>]*+>|\S)++\K|\s~',$string,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/FHczCC)

Output:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(24) "<strong>Blabla1</strong>"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Blaabla2<br />"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla3"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "<strong>Blaabla4</strong>"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla5"
  [5]=>
  string(20) "Blaabla6<br /><br />"
  [6]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla7"
  [7]=>
  string(44) "<span style='color:#B22222;'>Blaabla8</span>"
  [8]=>
  string(8) "Blaabla9"
}
```

The regex attempts to match a full tag, and if a full tag can't be consumed, it will consume one non-space character, then rinse and repeat. This will prevent tags from being split, which gives expected output for index 5 and 7.

**I wouldn't recommend doing this with regex, though.** I didn't consult the HTML specs when writing the regex, so the regex is very brittle and may break on input in the wild. You might want to learn how to parse HTML properly with one of the libraries listed in this question: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: thanks for your explanations ! I will see your link :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex

```
((?:<br\s*\/?>)+)|(?<!<br)\s+(?!\/?>)
```

Use this with `preg_replace` using `$1\n` as a replacement string, and then you can split by newline to get the array (removing empty ones).

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC7cY2/3).